# Generic type as a property of received argument

Tags: typescript

How can one assign a property of argument to a generic? Here's the code:

```
const foo = <T = ???someObject.bar???>(someObject: {[string]: any}): T => {
    return someObject.bar
}
```

How can `T` be assigned to the `bar` property of `someObject`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want the argument to have at least have the property `bar`, right?
This means it is a subtype of

```
interface WithBar<T> {
    bar: T
}
```

Using this, you can write your function in this way:

```
const foo = <T>(someObject: WithBar<T>): T => {
    return someObject.bar
}
```

To avoid introducing that artificial `WithBar` type, directly write

```
const foo = <T>(someObject: { bar: T }): T => {
    return someObject.bar
}
```

You may now use it generically:

```
const barFoo1 = { bar: "asdf", foo: "fdsa"};
const myBar1: string = foo(barFoo1);

const barFoo2 = { bar: 123, foo: 321};
const myBar2: number = foo(barFoo2);
```

Comment: By the way, if you want to directly pass objects written in object notation (object literals), you may encounter an error: Calling `foo({ bar: 123, foo: 321 })` yields `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'bar' does not exist in type  { bar: string }`. This raises from TypeScript's strict checking of fresh types, see https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/freshness.html. You can circumvent this by requiring your argument to have a subtype: `const foo = <T, X extends { bar: T }>(someObject: X): T => ...`